# Why does RTC source control attempt to force me to deliver change sets?

Tags: rtc

When checking in & delivering files I receive this message :

[image]

I do not want to deliver other change sets as part of this delivery of files ? Is there a reason RTC source control does this, how can it be prevented ?

Comment: Where exactly did you click to select "check-in and deliver"? What version of RTC are you using?

Comment: @VonC im using RTC version 3. Within 'pending changes' view I right clicked on the files and selected 'check in and deliver'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually avoid and don't recommend the "[check-in and deliver](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/t_delivering_changes.html)" option, especially since it will "complete" the change set and force the developer to create a *new* change set at the next check-in.
That means I ended up with *tons* of change sets delivered by developer unaware of this "feature".

To control what is delivered, it is best to check in, *and then* deliver.

[That thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/23362/question-on-check-in-and-deliver) mentions a situation similar to yours:

> The UI allows to select a change set and just check in and deliver this specific change set.
>   The controlling element is where you right click the outgoing changes.
>
> - If you right click a single change set you deliver just that.
> - If you right-click on outgoing you deliver all change sets
>
> I suspect from your description what happened is, there where several outgoing changes locally that needed check in.
>   The user selected the unresolved node and selected "check-in and deliver".
>   The result is that the changes where subsumed into a new change set and delivered.